# Why do level 4 and 5 Druid spells seem to change tone?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, lore, druid

I am playing a Druid for the first time (D&D 5e) and am quite enjoying it. My character recently hit level 9, and I noticed that the 4th and 5th level spells seem to shift in tone dramatically from earlier levels.

While lower level spells seem to emphasize beasts and nature thematically, the higher level spells seem to shift toward elementals and life force / necromancy style spells. Is there a reason for this?

In other words, is there lore behind the shift in tone and theme?

Or is there a tactical reason for this shift?

Or am I imagining things?

Comment: I'm answering based on the history of the game (I'm setting up a 2nd Ed. campaign right now, so the in-depth descriptions of how druids evolve as they level is still fresh in my mind), assuming that this isn't a developer-intent question but instead just trying to figure out why the class gets more esoteric around 9th level when it was formerly solidly grounded in what we think of as nature.  If you're looking for developer commentary, let me know and I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how it's been, at least since 2nd edition in the '90s.

Low-level druids are still mastering the "nature" of the Prime Material - learning to summon animals and draw on their aspects to enhance themselves.  But 4th and 5th level spells are beyond that introductory phase.  This is where you learn to manipulate the very building blocks of all nature - life energy and the elemental forces, as well as complex natural phenomena like diseases and disasters.  You still get some plant and animal related spells, but they're generally bigger in scope - summoning hordes or granting complete control over animals.  You also expand your control over nature to less "natural" monsters with spells like *charm monster*.

In much older editions of DnD, 9th level was considered "name level" - this is the point where you are your own political force to be reckoned with.  Lords and armies in the areas you're active have standing policies for you specifically, usually "placate if possible", and you're known across at least your continent, if not further.  On a meta level, it's *also* traditionally the point where "pure casters" like wizards and clerics are expected to surpass normal encounter design.  At this point you can skip entire adventure arcs using spells like *fly* and *teleport*.  The Druid's 5th level spells are equally game-changing:  you can raise the dead, undo permanent disabilities like petrification, make plants and animals have human-level intellects, wipe out an entire village or cripple a town with a single insect summoning, bind a person to complete a quest, or permanently reshape the land.